# $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql, hadoop2

I downloaded hive source and used following command for building.

```
mvn clean install -Phadoop-2,dist -DskipTests
```

Then I went to bin directory and executed hive using

```
bin # ./hive
Missing Hive Execution Jar: /tools/hive/lib/hive-exec-*.jar
```

To solve this I set

```
export HIVE_HOME=/tools/hive/packaging/target/apache-hive-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-bin/apache-hive-2.0.0-SNAPSHOT-bin
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and again

```
bin # ./hive
Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path
```

I have no hadoop on my machine. Can I run hive cli in standalone mode without Hadoop?

What is the general practice of using Hive cli?

Comment: Hive requires Hadoop.

Comment: You must Install Hadoop Before installinh Hive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it can be read on [Hive getting started wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-InstallationandConfiguration), the requisites are:

1. Java 1.7+
2. Hadoop 2.x

So I am afraid you can't run Hive standalone, why would you do that?